# Beam projector works in bootcamp, but do not work in macos

Tags: macos, display, bootcamp, hdmi

The HDMI beam projector in my classroom works fine when I boot with Bootcamp (win 10), but it shows "no signal" when I boot with macOS (10.14.6)

I have changed all the available screen resolutions, and tried rebooting, but it was useless.

But I think there should be a way to resolve this problem.

MBP 15" mid-2014.

Any ideas to solve my problem?

Comment: Is this happening when you keep the HDMI cable connected to the projector when you switch from Win to macOS? Try disconnecting the cable, switch from Win to macOS, then plug the cable back in.

Comment: @IconDaemon I did as your recommendation, But it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

HDMI on Macs is a curse, because Apple decided to take the HDMI spec more than just literally – not only do they rigorously enforce HDCP, but they take the unusual move of letting the *display* set the rules, not the host machine. Nor do Apple stick completely to the DisplayPort spec; getting 4K out of a 2013/2014 machine requires one part luck and one part voodoo – and you can forget about display daisychain :)

macOS is also extremely fussy about the output device resolutions that it will respond do – if the display signals (via EDID) to the Mac a resolution that doesn't exist in its lookup table, it goes all "talk to the hand, la la la …". To get macOS working with something it otherwise turns it's nose up at, you can either phone Apple Support and ask for an EDID Override file for that specific display device, or you can buy a copy of [SwitchResX](https://www.madrau.com/) which will let you edit in whatever display resolutions you like.

Comment: @BentonQuest, IconDaemon, Thank you for your suggestion, I will try SwitchResX tomorrow

Comment: I tried SwitchResX and it sometimes succeeds (totally two times in more than ten classes) but mostly it failed...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the screen resolution of MacOS is higher than your projector or vice-versa.

Have you checked the option **Scaled** from **Resolution** option on Display and give a try with a different option from 1920 to 1280? Check it should work in lower resolution 1280X720 at least.

You also check the maximum resolution support by your Projector.

Comment: Yes, I know there are more options when I click Scaled with [option] key, So I could try all the options from 600x400 to 2560x1440, 1080p, 1080i and so on. But it did not work.